# FullCalendar DayGrid view event ordering?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have an application where I am rendering a calendar with a dayGrid view. The specific settings of the view are:

```
views: {
            sevenDaySchedule: {
              type: 'dayGrid',
              duration: { days: 7 },
              buttonText: '7 day',
              dateAlignment: 'week',
              firstDay: 1, //Monday
              dateIncrement: { days: 7 },
            }
          },
        defaultView: 'sevenDaySchedule',
```

I am wondering if it is possible to re-order the events within each day of the calendar?

Basically, if I have 2 or more events in a single cell (day) on the calendar, can I make it so that the user can drag and drop the events within a single day to re-arrange / re-order them?

If I have this: [image: EventOrder1]

Is it possible to achieve this:[image: EventOrder2]

Without having to rename the events every time?

I want to just be able to drag and drop events into their desired order and have them stay that way. Is it possible to achieve this where the events automatically rename themselves with the appropriate prefix ( 1), 2), 3), etc.) after being dragged and dropped?

Comment: No. The events are displayed in chronological order. It's a calendar, calendars display events in the order they are going to happen. That's their entire purpose. If you want a list of events with a random / user-defined order then don't use a calendar, just make your own list instead.

Comment: You can have some influence over the exact ordering algorithm - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventOrder, but you can't drag the events into a random order. You can drag them to another day - because that definably alters their start date. And if you use the timeGrid view you can drag them to another time of day - again altering their date/time in a defined way. But you can't drag them within the same day in the month view because there's no concept of time there (only days), so there's nowhere to move the event to - you can't alter its start time by doing that...therefore you can't drag